# No coloured output on Jenkins console from bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins scripted pipeline which is making a salt call and running a bash script. The Script has some colour code as outlined below. I have the ANSI Color enabled. However, the colour are not getting resolved. Instead they are getting printed as is but in blue colour as ANSI color i have set "Default Foreground" to Blue. I tried with Jenkins Default color as well but no luck.

```
?[31;43m***** HOSTNAME INFORMATION *****?[0m

?[31;43m***** FILE SYSTEM DISK SPACE USAGE *****?[0m

?[31;43m***** TOP 5 MEMORY-CONSUMING PROCESSES *****?[0m
```

Comment: Try replacing `?` with `\e` which is ASCII's escape character. example: `echo -e "\e[31;43mTEST\e[m"`

Answer (score 1):

Your escape sequences are wrong. Additionally, the **-e** flag does not work on MacOs (If you are working in MacOs).

```
#!/bin/bash

content='\e[31;43m***** HOSTNAME INFORMATION *****\e[0m

\e[31;43m***** FILE SYSTEM DISK SPACE USAGE *****\e[0m

\e[31;43m***** TOP 5 MEMORY-CONSUMING PROCESSES *****\e[0m\n
'

echo -e "$content" ## Does not work on MacOs
printf "$content" ## But you can use printf and add a \n at the end of string.
```

Comment: See this script here: https://www.tecmint.com/using-shell-script-to-automate-linux-system-maintenance-tasks/ using this as an example. The ? char is what I get on the Jenkins console.  I'm on ubuntu and the echo is having -e option as outlined in the example link.

Comment: In your example you have **?** instead of **\e**. The link you shared has the right syntax but somehow you got the wrong one.